# python restart the program after running a method

Tags: python

A noob question I'm sure.
For example, say I have a program that looks something like this.

```
def method1():
    #do something here

def method2():
    #do something here

#this is the menu
menu=input("What would you like to do?\ntype 1 for method1 or 2 for method2: ")
if(menu=="1"):
    method1()
if(menu=="2"):
    method2()
```

How can I make this menu appear again after a method has finished instead of the program terminating?

I was thinking I could wrap the whole program into an endless loop, but that doesn't feel right :P

Comment: I'd do it with an endless loop (or not endless, depending on whatever else you're doing).

Comment: Wrap it non-endless loop were there is choice to exit the program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while True:
    #this is the menu
    menu=input("What would you like to do?\ntype 1 for method1 or 2 for method2: ")
    if(menu=="1"):
        method1()
    if(menu=="2"):
        method2()
```

If the endless loop "doesn't feel right", ask yourself when and why it should end. Should you have a third input option that exits the loop? Then add:

```
if menu == "3":
    break
```

Comment: thanks this is great. I was gonna put the whole thing inside the loop, methods and everything xD

Comment: Well... you never really want to wrap "the whole program" in a loop; you want to wrap **the part that needs to loop** in a loop. :)

Answer (score 0):

An endless loop is the way to do it though, something like this:

```
running = true

def method1(): 
   #do something here

def method2():
    #do something here

def stop():
    running = false

while running:
    #this is the menu
    menu=input("What would you like to do?\ntype 1 for method1 or 2 for method2 (3 to stop): ")
    if(menu=="1"):
        method1()
    if(menu=="2"):
       method2()
    if(menu=="3"):
       stop()
```

Comment: Russels method is better than this